# Snappy Mail/Rainloop Authentication failed

Tags: mail-server, crypt, dovecot, cyber-panel, rainloop

I Installed the fresh cyberpanel installation when I created a email with the domain and tried to login with the same it shows

> Authentication failed
> Server message: AUTHENTICATIONFAILED Authentication failed.

I am using VPS server from contabo:

**OS: Ubuntu 18.04 (64 Bit)**

Installed Cyperpanel using below command.

```
sh <(curl https://cyberpanel.net/install.sh || wget -O - https://cyberpanel.net/install.sh)
```

When I checked for the errors I got below Error:

> Sep 14 19:44:42 vmi1011202.contaboserver.net dovecot[733]: auth-worker(1939): Error: sql(admin@mydoamin.com,127.0.0.1,<TgoNr6boGLp/AAAB>): Invalid password in passdb: crypt() failed: Invalid argument
> Sep 14 19:44:44 vmi1011202.contaboserver.net dovecot[733]: imap-login: Disconnected (auth failed, 1 attempts in 2 secs): user=admin@mydoamin.com, method=PLAIN, rip=127.0.0.1, lip=127.0.0.1, TLS, session=<TgoNr6boGLp/AAAB>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because of dovecot version once we upgrade devecot from 2.2.x to 2.3.x it'll work.

Follow below steps.

Add the reposity key of dovecot to the rpm key store:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 18A348AEED409DA1
```

Add the official dovecot Ubuntu Repo to sources.list
(this example is for Ubuntu 18)

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dovecot.list
```

insert into:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.dovecot.org/ce-2.3-latest/ubuntu/bionic/ bionic main
```

Save it and close editor

Do a:

```
sudo apt update
```

Do a:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

Reboot your machine.

```
reboot
```